# How to link or route the react semantic UI dropdown component

Tags: javascript, reactjs, jsx

I am a newbie to React. I am trying to add links to the React semantic UI dropdown menu. Following is the component that I fetched from React semantic UI

```
import React from "react";
import { Dropdown } from "semantic-ui-react";
import { BrowserRouter as Router, Route, Link } from "react-router-dom";

const trigger = (
  <span style={{ marginTop: "2px" }}>
    <i aria-hidden="true" class="user big icon" size="big" />
  </span>
);
const options = [
  { key: "user", text: "Account", icon: "user", to: "/accounts" },
  { key: "settings", text: "Settings", icon: "settings", to: "/settings" },
  { key: "sign-out", text: "Sign Out", icon: "sign out", to: "/sign-out" }
];

const DropdownMenu = () => (
  <Dropdown
    trigger={trigger}
    options={options}
    pointing="top right"
    icon={null}
  />
);

export default DropdownMenu;
```

I tried adding "to" keyword to the options array and have added the Route paths to the Router which lies in a different component but it's not working. Any help would be appreciated, Thank you.

Answer (score 5):

Or you can use **Dropdown.Menu** and **Dropdown.Item**. Each Dropdown.Item can have param `as={Link} to='/somewhere'/`.

```
import React from "react";
import { Dropdown } from "semantic-ui-react";
import { Link } from "react-router-dom";

const trigger = (
    <span style={{ marginTop: "2px" }}>
        <i aria-hidden="true" class="user big icon" size="big" />
    </span>
);

const DropdownMenu = () => (
    <Dropdown trigger={trigger} pointing='top left' icon={null}>
        <Dropdown.Menu>
            <Dropdown.Item text='Account' icon='user' as={Link} to='/accounts'/>
            <Dropdown.Item text='Settings' icon='settings' as={Link} to='/settings'/>
            <Dropdown.Item text='Sign Out' icon='sign out' as={Link} to='/sign-out'/>
        </Dropdown.Menu>
    </Dropdown>
);

export default DropdownMenu;
```

I hope it will help you.

Answer (score 3):

You can try something like this. change the key **to** to **value** in you options array. then use `onChange` method to handle the selection. You may want to pass the **history** prop from parent component down to the component you want to invoke the action if its not available.

```
import React, { Component } from "react";
import ReactDOM from "react-dom";
import { Dropdown, Form } from "semantic-ui-react";

const trigger = (
  <span style={{ marginTop: "2px" }}>
    <i aria-hidden="true" class="user big icon" size="big" />
  </span>
);

const options = [
  { key: "user", text: "Account", icon: "user", value: "/accounts" },
  { key: "settings", text: "Settings", icon: "settings", value: "/settings" },
  { key: "sign-out", text: "Sign Out", icon: "sign out", value: "/sign-out" }
];

class App extends Component {
  move = (e, { value }) => {
    this.props.history.push('value')
  }

  render() {
    return (
      <div>
        <Dropdown
          options={options}
          trigger={trigger}
          icon={null}
          onChange={this.move}
        />
      </div>
    );
  }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

My solution based on the answer from Jan Fara:

```
import React from 'react';
import { Dropdown } from 'semantic-ui-react';
import Avatar from 'react-avatar';
import { Link } from 'react-router-dom';

function DropdownuserMenu() {
  const trigger = (
    <span>
      <Avatar name='Happy User' size="40"/>
    </span>
  );
  return (
    <Dropdown trigger={trigger} pointing='top left' icon={null}>
      <Dropdown.Menu>
        <Dropdown.Item text='Account' icon='user' as={Link} to='/accounts'/>
        <Dropdown.Item text='Settings' icon='settings' as={Link} to='/settings'/>
        <Dropdown.Item text='Sign Out' icon='sign out' as={Link} to='/sign-out'/>
      </Dropdown.Menu>
    </Dropdown>
  );
}
export default DropdownuserMenu;
```